# How to get items of only activated user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have two models `users` and `items`. I only want to show items of activated users only. So that when a user deactivates their account, their items do not get returned.

`users.js`

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  isDeactivated: Boolean,
});

export default mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

`items.js`

```js
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
});

export default mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);
```

So, when I run the query `Item.find({})`, I want to return only items of activated user.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is going to be a tricky one but lets see.

```
Item.find().populate('user').execPopulate()
.then(item => {
  // Will return list of item and respective user details
  const itemWithUserDetails = item.map(data => {
      return {
        userId: {
           ...data.user._doc
        }
        name: data.name
      }   
  })
  console.log(itemWithUserDetails)
  // Will return list of item and respective user details of activated users
  const filteredUserItem= itemWithUserDetails.filter(user => {
    return user.userId.isDeactivated !== false
  })
  console.log(filteredUserItem)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

I haven't tested the code tho but it will likely work

Answer (score 0):

You should try following query

```
 const activatedUserInfo =    (await Item.find().pupulate("user")).map(item=>item.user.isDeactivated !== false)
```